# streaming the video from webcam and play it on other computer

Tags: java, networking, video-streaming, webcam

i have a project to do recently. what i have to do goes like following:

1. obtain the realtime video from the camera on the client side
2. stream and forward it to the server
3. play it on the server side

i've done some research about this and i know jmf and webcam-capture can do 1 and 3 for me. the real point that makes me stuck is the second point.

i didn't do networking programming as much as i should and i could not find the right idea to achieve this. how can i convert a captured video clip to a videostream(no sound needed by the way) and send it to the server in realtime?

all i need is just a guide to the proper api.

thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) to connect the client and server.  You can find examples in the Java Tutorials, try using an ObjectStream

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy indeed. Use Windows Media Encoder to capture and stream your webcam to any other computer.

When your encoder starts, you will get a URL to view your stream, which you can use to view the stream (With audio and video) from anywhere with internet.